# Fundamental domain of a Fuchsian group which is not locally finite

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

I am trying to understand Example 9.2.5 in Beardon's book *The Geometry of Discrete Groups*.  The goal is to construct a fundamental domain of a Fuchsian group which is not locally finite.

Definitions used by Beardon: A *fundamental domain* is a connected open subset $D \subseteq H^2$ such that (1) for some $S$ satisfying $D \subseteq S \subseteq \overline{D}$, we have $\bigcup_{g \in G}  gS = H^2$ and $S \cap gS = \varnothing$ if $g \ne 1$; and (2) hyperbolic area of $\partial D$ is 0.  ($\overline{D}$ means the closure of $D$ in $H^2$.)  The fundamental domain $D$ is said to be *locally finite* if for each compact subset $X \subseteq H^2$, we have $gX \cap \overline{D} \ne \varnothing$ for only finitely many $g \in G$.

Beardon's counterexample is the group $G$ generated by the transformations of the upper half plane $$f(z) = 2z,\,\,\, g(z) = \frac{3z+4}{2z+3}.$$
He first constructs the fundamental domain $D$ (which *is* locally finite) as the region bounded (in the Euclidean sense) by the semicircles joining -2 to -1, -1 to 1, 1 to 2, and 2 to -2.  (Figure 9.2.3 in the book, see below)

[image: The fundamental domain D (which is locally finite)]

The remainder of the construction is illustrated in the next figure below (Figure 9.2.5 in the book)  First, we replace the left half of $D$ by its image under $g$.  The new region has a boundary segment $[i,2i]$ as well as the semicircles joining 1 to $g(i)$, then $g(i)$ to $g(2i)$, and $g(2i)$ to 2.  Then we replace the hyperbolic triangle $(w,1,2w)$ by its image under $f$, which is $(2w,2,4w)$.  Everything okay so far.  But then Beardon says:

> Each *Euclidean* segment $[\zeta, 2\zeta]$, where $\zeta$ lies on $|z|=1$ and is *strictly* between $w$ and $i$, is replaced by the equivalent segment $[\zeta', 2\zeta']$.

($\zeta$ and $\zeta'$ are labeled as $z$ and $z'$ in the image below.)

I don't understand how $[\zeta, 2\zeta]$ is equivalent to $[\zeta', 2\zeta']$ under an element of the group $G$, for *all* $\zeta$ on the arc between $w$ and $i$.  The transformation that takes $[\zeta, 2\zeta]$ to $[\zeta', 2\zeta']$ is multiplication by $(\zeta'/\zeta)$, which varies as $\zeta$ varies, so these transformations can't all be in $G$ (since it's a discrete group).  Can someone explain what's going on here?

[image: Modification of the domain D]

Comment: From what you write, this certainly does seem like a serious problem to me. Since I do not have a copy of the book handy, can you say what definition the author is using for a fundamental domain and for local finiteness thereof?

Comment: @LeeMosher Definitions edited in at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just very simple Euclidean geometry: if you take any point on the Euclidean segment $[\zeta', 2\zeta']$ then there exists a dilation by some power of 2 (which is an element of your group $G$) which takes this point to the vertical region between 1 and 2 (and above some arcs). For instance, if $\zeta=w$ as in the picture, then it is dilation by 2.  Another way to see this is to take the above vertical region and apply to it dilations of the form $z\mapsto 2^{-n}z$, $n$ is a natural number. The images will cover a part of the right half-plane containing the portion of the annulus satisfying $0\le Re(z)\le 1$.

Comment: Thanks! I got it now. My mistake was thinking that $[\zeta, 2\zeta]$ had to map *monotonically* onto $[\zeta', 2\zeta']$, whereas actually $\zeta$ can map to some point in the middle of $[\zeta', 2\zeta']$.  For a simpler case, if the transformation were $x \mapsto x+1$, then we could replace $[0,1]$ with $[2.7,3.7]$ by mapping $0 \mapsto 3, \ldots, 0.7 \mapsto 3.7$, and then points from 0.7 to 1 cover 2.7 to 3.